# Privileges to users in Apache Zeppelin from users in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, privileges, apache-zeppelin

I have set up a PostgreSQL database and created three users:

```
- admin (all privileges) 
- user1 (access table1_for_user1)
- user2 (access table2_for_user2)
```

So same I created base this (somedatabase) and in it two tables:

```
table1_for_user1
table2_for_user2
```

It is logical to understand that if I configure the connection in Apache Zeppelin as administrator (admin), I will be able to make a selection on both tables of the database. In Apache Zeppelin, I have created two users too:

```
- user1
- user2
```

How do I correctly configure the database connection to apply privileges to users in Apache Zeppelin.

Thanks. 
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve:

- Step 1: Create in Interpreters two users connection to DB
- Step 2: In permissions add only user N all columns.